# How do I make Thunderbird add events from Exchange invites to my Google Calender

Tags: thunderbird, exchange, google-calendar, lightning

I've set-up Thunderbird, Lightning and the Google Bi-directional Calender provider and it's all working fine. I can manually add events to either calender and also access the Google calender via the embedded web tab. However I get a lot of meeting invites at work from exchange. Now Lighting is working correctly I can accept them but the entries are always added to the local calender. How do I make my Google calender the default destination for accepted invite entries?

Comment: In the end I gave up and installed the Google Calender Sync plugin on my corporate Windows boxen and synced that way.